# Basic undo/redo logic with closures

Tags: c#, closures

I am trying to grasp the concept of closures in c#. Basically trying to capture values and xBefore and yBefore with closures

here is my code

```
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    Action PerformOperation(bool move, bool undo, int x1, int y1)
    {
        Action operationMove = null;
        Action operationUndo = null;
        int xBefore = 0;
        int yBefore = 0; 

        operationMove = () => 
        {
                xBefore = x;
                yBefore = y;
                x = x1;
                y = y1;
                Debug.Log(" -- Move Operation -- " + " xBefore " +xBefore+ " yBefore " +yBefore+ " x " +x+ " y " +y);
        };

        operationUndo = () => 
        {
                x = xBefore;
                y = yBefore;
                Debug.Log(" -- Undo Operation -- " + " xBefore " +xBefore+ " yBefore " +yBefore+ " x " +x+ " y " +y);
        };

        if (move)
            return operationMove;
        if (undo)
            return operationUndo;
        return null;
    }
```

And then call the Action in my start function

```
Action operation = PerformOperation (true,false,5,5);
        operation ();
        operation       = PerformOperation (true, false, 15, 15);
        operation ();
        operation       = PerformOperation (true, false, 30, 30);
        operation ();
        operation       = PerformOperation (false, true, 10, 10);
        operation ();
```

Basically, perform a move or undo operation based on the boolean variables passed in the PerformOperation. So xBefore and yBefore keeps track of x and y before it gets updated by operationMove action. operationUndo is called similar way and then finally return one of the two actions

The first 3 calls to move tracks the xBefore and yBefore values correctly. However the last call to undo just returns all 0 values and doesn't keep track of the states so far. I am assuming every time I initialize operation =  PerformOperatio(..) .. a new set of actions are created?

How can I correctly implement basic undo logic with closures then?

Comment: Yes, when you create a new action, you delete all previous info. Why do you need closures? Use OOP.

Comment: thanks. yes i can do it with OOP. i just wanted to understand how closures work and came across some tutorials where they mention closures for undo/redo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The local variables being captured by the closure are effectively re-created each time you call the method where those local variables are declared. The example you have is doomed to fail, because you only ever return a closure that has captured the latest instance of those local variables.

It seems to me that instead what you should be doing is having the method itself perform the operation, and then have the method return the `Action` delegate that will *undo* the operation just done.

For example, something like this:

```cs
Action PerformOperation(int x1, int y1)
{
    int xBefore = x, yBefore = y;

    x = x1; y = y1;

    return () => { x = xBefore; y = yBefore; };
}
```

I can't be more specific without a more complete code example. But I think the above more closely matches what you would expect for the code to do.

Then, when you want to *do* the operation, you call the method, and when you want to *undo* the operation, you invoke the `Action` delegate that was returned by the method when you *did* the operation.

A multi-level undo/redo interface will require somewhat more elaborate handling than the above, but it will still be based on the same fundamental idea: there are multiple instances of the captured variables, one instance of each variable for each time the method is called.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can slightly change your code and move `xBefore` and `yBefore` out from `PerformOperation`. I think it works as you expected. So, current and old values are inside closure of `operationUndo` and `operationMove`

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int xBefore = 0;
int yBefore = 0; 

Action PerformOperation(bool move, bool undo, int x1, int y1)
{
    Action operationMove = null;
    Action operationUndo = null;


    operationMove = () => ...
```